# Sudo seemingly not obeying -S parameter

Tags: linux, sudo, stdin

I am running some scripts as part of pre/post deploy using DeployHQ, I need to be able to call the script on one line and for there to be no feedback from the terminal so I want to pass the password into the sudo command (instead of sudo asking for the password at the time of use)

I am trying to get `sudo` to work with `stdin` by doing something like;

```
echo my_password | sudo -S chown -R my_user:www-data /srv/www/my_site/public_html/
```

But what is getting returned is;

```
[sudo] password for my_user: 
 Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for my_user: 
 sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt
```

The password in question is correct and when the command is ran without `-S` and the user is prompted for the password is works.

Could someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Just to clarify - I want there to still be a password, just one that I can pass in.

Comment: I think your problem is described here:http://serverfault.com/questions/510888/sudo-u-fails-with-env-u-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: did you ever figure out what your problem was? I'm having the exact same issue and I've tried everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the sudo manual:

The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the standard input instead of the terminal device. **The password must be followed by a newline character.** This means you should end password with \n

EDIT: I did a couple of test, and honestly in my test system your syntax works correctly. ( echo mypass | sudo -S .... )

2nd EDIT: Try with the following syntax: `echo -e "mypass\n" | sudo -S command`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I hadn't noticed the newline character requirement before (mine just says `-S  The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the standard input instead of the terminal device.`) - I have tried this to no avail.

Comment: have you tried the syntax I posted with the -e parameter to echo? echo -e "mypass\n" | sudo -S command

Comment: Yeah I did, unfortunately nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is wrong

However, if you want to run sudo without being prompted for a password, you can do so by editing the sudo configuration file.  To do this use the command `visudo`

The default file has lots of examples so just search for `NOPASSWD` and you should find an example to get you started

Comment: I do want to require a password, just not be prompted - I will edit my question to reflect this.