# sudo -u fails with env: -u: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

On Ubuntu 12.04, when I do

```
sudo -u <user> ls
```

I get

```
env: -u: No such file or directory
```

This happens for any command and any user for `<user>`, including myself and root.

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Show `which sudo` and `sudo -l` as your user, please

Comment: it looks like sudo does not recognize "-u" as a flag and tries to run a command named "-u".

Comment: Ah that was it.   `which sudo` was `/usr/bin/sudo`, but @PetterH's comment clued me in to the fact there might be an alias set up for sudo.   Sure enough...

Comment: yep, I forgot `type sudo`

Answer (score 5):

Turns out `sudo` was actually running an alias:

```
$ alias sudo
alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH'
```

Running `/usr/bin/sudo` directly skipped the alias and resolved the problem.

Alternatively, you can open the `.bashrc` file in your home directory and comment out the line:

```
alias sudo='sudo env PATH=$PATH'
```

Run `source .bashrc` again, and (for good measure), run `unalias sudo`.